# Configure log-specific olddir for pattern matched logs in logrotate

Tags: logrotate

Is there a way to make log-rotate include the source file in the name of it's archive directory?

For security reasons I keep a very long history of Apache logs.  With several sites running on this server, Apache stores a large number of logs.  Once multiplied with rotation, my archive directory is *huge*.

I would like to create log specific archive directories. Eg set:

```
olddir /var/log/apache2/www.example.com-access.log/
```

but at the moment my configuration is based on a pattern:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        dateext
        daily
        rotate 365
        missingok
        notifempty
        olddir /var/log/archive/apache2
}
```

Without writing a specific configuration for every one of Apache's (many) logs, is there a way that I can place rotated files in a log-specific directory?

Comment: I was sending logs to a remote server when I had a 400+ vhosts Apache server. Much more lighter on I/O and on the remote syslog server you can choose between having file logs per date or per host/date.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Out of interest what was your solution for clearing down old logs? AFAIK rsyslog doesn't do this and Logrotate can't manage ready rotated logs.

Comment: Was keeping 1 year worth of logs in a central syslog server separated in daily files with syslog-ng+logrotate. Nothing fancy. We also had backups rotations on tape, and made a captive tape every 6 months. If I really had to restore something older than 1 year, only from tape